# Prove that an element of a group is in a one-element conjugacy class if and only if it commutes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove that an element $g$ of a group $G$ is in a one-element conjugacy class if and only if it commutes with all of $G$.  The "only-if" direction is easy:

Suppose $g$ commutes with all of $G$ and let $g' = hgh^{1}$ then $g' = hh^{-1}g = g$ so the only element of its conjugacy class is $g$ itself.

I've been struggling hard with the other direction.  I've tried a direct proof:

Suppose $g$ is the only element of its conjugacy class and let $h\in G$.  Then ... $hg =$ um ... Well, we know $g \ne khk^{-1}$ for any k.  That includes $g$ itself so $g\ne ghg^{-1}$ which implies $e \ne hg^{-1}$ ...  Well I could also try it with $g^{-1}$ so that $g\ne g^{-1}hg$.  I could try it with the identity.  That just shows $g\ne h$ ...

I've tried a contrapositive proof:

Suppose $h\in G$ is some element for which $gh\ne hg$.  Then let $g' = kgk^{-1}$ for some $k$.  ... Hrm.

So I'm stuck.  Any help please?

Comment: This is basically definition, if $ak\ne ka$ for some $k$, then $k^{-1}ak\ne a$ by multiply by $k^{-1}$ on the left, and the conjugacy class has size at least $2$.

Comment: @Adam Hughes, I don't follow--this just proves that, for the $k$ for which $a$ does not commute, then that $k$ also doesn't conjugate with $a$.  How do I know there isn't some other conjugate with $a$?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the direction that prove is:  "$a$ is non-central implies $a$ has a non-trivial conjugate."

Of course $a$ could have other conjugates, but the statement only requires at least $2$, which that solution provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\{g\}$ is a conjugacy class of cardinality $1$, then for every $x \in G$ apparently, $x^{-1}gx$ belongs to this conjugacy class, so must be equal to $g$. So $x^{-1}gx=g$ and that means $gx=xg$ for all $x \in G$, in other words, $g$ commutes with all elements of $G$ (one says $g$ is central). If this holds for any $g \in G$, then the group must be abelian.